# Preventing Duplicate Meta Errors in Multi-page Sections

Tags: seo, blog, rel-canonical

I'm getting duplicate meta description errors in Google Search Console on the categories of my blog. As new posts are added and cap the amount of posts per page, a new page is created (Global Marketing Page 1, 2, 3...so on).

Does it make sense to put rel=canonical tags on these pages, even if they have different content per page? (Website on WordPress)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Word Press?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, should have specified in my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Canonical links will help for page content but they do not help against duplicate titles and meta descriptions. WordPress is notorious for adding duplicate titles and meta descriptions whenever using [Pagination](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination).

Google Search Console will nag about this until you make your titles and descriptions unique. You need not write a whole new description or title but simply add a page number as a suffix or prefix.

This can easily be done by using [Yoast SEO](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) for WordPress which has a big range of other SEO benefits. Once you install this plugin you simply find the blog page and edit the description/title and add one of [Yoasts variables](https://kb.yoast.com/kb/yoast-wordpress-seo-titles-metas-template-variables/) to it.

*For example the [BYBE blog](https://www.bybe.net/blog/) uses:*

- Title: `The %%sitename%% Blog about Web Design and SEO %%page%%`

  - Renders as: The BYBE Blog about Web Design and SEO - Page 2 of 5
- Desc: `Visit the BYBE blog %%page%%. Articles about web design, SEO, graphic design and content management systems such as WordPress.`

  - Renders as: Visit the BYBE blog - Page 2 of 5. Articles about web design, SEO, graphic design and content management systems such as WordPress.

Viewing the source you can see many other benefits such as previous and next, [twitter cards](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/overview) and [Open Graph](http://ogp.me/).

*There are many varibles that you can customise your titles and descriptions, including:*

- `%%date%%` ~ Replaced with the date of the post/page
- `%%title%%` ~ Replaced with the title of the post/page
- `%%parent_title%%` ~  Replaced with the title of the parent page of the current page
- `%%sitename%%` ~ The site's name
- `%%sitedesc%%` ~ The site's tagline / description
- `%%excerpt%%` ~ Replaced with the post/page excerpt (or auto-generated if it does not exist)
- `%%excerpt_only%%` ~ Replaced with the post/page excerpt (without auto-generation)
- `%%tag%%` ~ Replaced with the current tag/tags
- `%%category%%` ~ Replaced with the post categories (comma separated)
- `%%primary_category%%` ~ Replaced with the primary category of the post/page
- `%%category_description%%` ~ Replaced with the category description
- `%%tag_description%%` ~ Replaced with the tag description
- `%%term_description%%` ~ Replaced with the term description
- `%%term_title%%` ~ Replaced with the term name
- `%%searchphrase%%` ~ Replaced with the current search phrase
- `%%sep%%` ~ The separator defined in your theme's wp_title() tag.

However should you not want to use a plugin then you would need to edit your functions file, there is various ways this can be done but here's one method on WordPress Stack

> [SOURCE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/52157/24663)
>
> To add a page number *regardless* to any plugin … use filters. Do not
>   change the plugin file. You cannot run updates other wise.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> <?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
> /**
>  * Plugin Name: T5 Add page number to title
>  * Description: Adds <code> | Page $number</code> to the page title.
>  * License:     MIT
>  * License URI: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
>  */
>
> if ( ! function_exists( 't5_add_page_number' ) )
> {
>   function t5_add_page_number( $s )
>   {
>       global $page;
>       $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
>       ! empty ( $page ) && 1 < $page && $paged = $page;
>
>       $paged > 1 && $s .= ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page: %s' ), $paged );
>
>       return $s;
>   }
>
>   add_filter( 'wp_title', 't5_add_page_number', 100, 1 );
>   add_filter( 'wpseo_metadesc', 't5_add_page_number', 100, 1 );
> }
> ```

Please note that any WordPress development related questions should be asked on the WordPress stack. I've only added this as an example.

Comment: Thank you @Simon that was just what I needed